# sequelize findAll() return only one record

Tags: sequelize.js

I try to get records from db.

```
db.relations.findAll({where: {organisation: orgName}})
        .then(found => {
            console.log('Found relations by name: ', found[0].dataValues);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });
```

And I get only one record but db have more than one records with same name.

Then I try findAll without params

```
db.relations.findAll()
        .then(found => {
            console.log('Found relations by name: ', found[0].dataValues);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });
```

And I get again one record with id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the first value of the array, using `found[0]`.
It will be one record.

Also if you need just the data and not the sequelize instance,
The you can add a raw property

Something like

```
Model.findAll({where: {your clause}, raw: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I had seeded data with a mismatch of string value for the attribute I was using. Probably not likely your issue but worth a double check.

Defined on migration file

```
status: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  defaultValue: 'DRAFT',
  values: ['ACTIVE', 'ARCHIVED', 'DRAFT']
}
```

However, I was looking for 'COMPLETE'.